# Is there a way that make `$this->$key` be declared as protected or private rather than public

Tags: php

I have this method in a class using PHP

```
public function setRows(string $key, array $value)
{
    $this->$key = $value;
}
```

Is there a way that make `$this->$key` be declared as protected or private rather than public?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically add a private property to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415023/dynamically-add-a-private-property-to-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

You must declare all possible keys as private, or you can use only one private property to hold all keys

```php
class Foo {
    private $data;

    public function setRows(string $key, array $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function getRows(string $key)
    {
        return $this->data[$key];
    }
}
```